# How can i create a facebook post in my app that looks alike a YouTube post

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, slcomposeviewcontroller

You know when you share a video from youtube to facebook, on facebook the post appears like this:

[image: facebook post shared from youtube]

How can I achieve the same result when I share a video link from my app?

I was able to share a post with text and image as a link (the text on top of the image) using the SLComposeViewController class. I called the setInitialText, addImage, and addURL methods to set the text, image, and url respectively.

But I was not able to figure out how to make the thumbnail image on the left and the description of the video on the right. Please point me to the right direction. --> :)

Thanks

Comment: Hi T.D have got the soluetion. I too need same requirement but with the image instead of video